# Make ARGV[0] optional in command line Ruby

Tags: ruby, command-line, args

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'yaml'
require 'json'
require 'getoptlong'
DEFAULT_CONF_FILE = 'conf.yaml'

    opts = GetoptLong.new(
        [ '--asn', '-a', GetoptLong::OPTIONAL_ARGUMENT ],
        [ '--modify', '-m', GetoptLong::OPTIONAL_ARGUMENT ]
    )

    config_file = ARGV[0]
    if config_file.to_s.empty?
      config_file = DEFAULT_CONF_FILE
    end

    opts.each do |opt, arg|
      case opt
        when '--asn'
          write_asn_database(arg,config_file)
        when '--modify'
          generate_modify_conf_file(arg,config_file)
      end
    end
```

This code generates some json files according to the given YAML configuration file. And what I am trying to do is:

- If in the command line is given a conf file, the program will use that given file;
- If not, it will use the default file.

Something like:

Example 1 (with a conf file):

```
$ ./my_script.rb new_conf_file.yaml -a
```

Example 2 (without conf file):

```
$ ./my_script.rb -a
```

The first example works, the second example gives me the following error:

```
 No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - -a (Errno::ENOENT)
```

And it makes sense because the program assumes that the option `-a` is a file.

I'm new to Ruby and I never used the command line to run scripts.

Comment: Use OptionParser instead of GetoptLong. OptionParser was written to make it much easier. There are other gems, not part of the Standard Library, that also do similar things, but OptionParser comes with Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I would post it here. Please do not do this, since it’s just ugly:

```
config_file = ARGV[0]
unless File.exist?(config_file)
  config_file = DEFAULT_CONF_FILE
end
```

Comment: I understand that this is not the best way to do it, but it works, thank you very much for your patience @mudasobwa

Comment: In fact it does not work. For instance, if you have a file named `-a` or `-a arg1` (with a space) in your directory, this code will fail to recognize it as an argument, rather thinking it’s the desired file. This solution has many other glitches as well. What looks working is not necessarily robust.

Comment: Oh... I see... In fact it is a big problem... But all the files to be used with this script will have the extension .yaml, so probably it won't be a big deal. Thank you again @mudasobwa

Answer (score 0):

From the very first paragraph of [`GetoptLong` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/getoptlong/rdoc/GetoptLong.html):

> The empty option `--` (two minus symbols) is used to end option processing. **This can be particularly important if options have optional arguments.**

Use your code by calling a script as:

```
#                 ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓  
./my_script.rb -a -- new_conf_file.yaml
```

Also, one should put the `opts` reading part **before** dealing with `ARGV` explicitly.

And no, with `GetoptLong` it is impossible to parse the command line you provided properly.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself correctly.
Yes -a has an optional argument, but it is the name of the json file to be generated.
It will run something like:
./my_script.rb new_conf.yaml -a my_new_file.json

If I don't parse the file name to be generated it will use a default one. And that part it's not the problem that I have at the moment, the problem is making the ARGV[0] optional.

But thank you for your suggestion I didn't know about the empty option :) @mudasobwa

Comment: @mf370 I understood from your comment only that you did not understand my answer. The way I described is the only way to pass optional argument `new_conf_file.yaml` to your script. **The only possible way.** And it is clearly stated in the documentation for `GeotoptLong` class that I linked.

Comment: Alright, I get it now. The `GetoptLong` doesn't work as I was expecting. Thank you @mudasobwa

Comment: One should not blame `GetoptLong`, this is how the console works in general. Unless you are to write a cumbersome homemade command line argument parser, you are to stick with the solution I suggested. That is how everyone in the world works with command line arguments.

Comment: I'm not blaming `GetoptLong`, but I know there are other options to parse arguments in Ruby, I just need to learn how to use them :)

Comment: Would you mind to explain what’s wrong with ⇑? I doubt there is a solution that provides a command line argument parsing as you want, just because it violates all the rules.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your solution, but I was asked to have a script running in a certain way, and I'm trying to find out how to do it and unfortunately your solution doesn't fit what I was asked for and there is nothing wrong with that, in fact I already learned some stuff with your answer :)